# calling superagent methods from before/after functions in mocha unit tests

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, superagent

I'm trying to delete a user which is created during mocha unit test in the after method but it doesn't work, I'm new to mocha and nodejs in general so appreciate the insight

```
var request = require('superagent');
.
.
after(function(){
request.del(baseurl + 'api/users/' + id)
    .end(function(e, res){
        console.log(res.body);
    });
});
```

below is the whole test file

```
var request = require('superagent');
var expect  = require('expect.js');
var baseurl = 'http://localhost:5000/';

var name = makeid(7);
var email = makeid(7) + '@someemail.com';
var id;

function makeid(s)
{
var text = "";
var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

for( var i=0; i < s; i++ )
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

 return text;
}

before(function(){
console.log("before")
});
describe('Test', function(){
beforeEach(function(){
    console.log("..........")
});

it('Create User', function(done){
    request.post(baseurl + 'api/users')
        .send({     name: name
            , email: email
        })
        .end(function(e,res){
            console.log("res.text: " + res.text)
            console.log("res.status: " + res.status)
            id = res.body._id;
            console.log("Retrieved id is : " + id)
            done()
        })
   });
//THIS WORKS
it('Delete', function(done){
    console.log("deleting created user.")
    request.del(baseurl + 'api/users/' + id)
        .end(function(e, res){
            console.log(res.body);
            done()
        })
});
 });
  //THIS DOESNT
 after(function(){
request.del(baseurl + 'api/users/' + id)
    .end(function(e, res){
        console.log("NOTHING GETS PRINTED HERE");
    });

console.log("deleted")
 });
```

Comment: Can you paste your test block and also are you sure that your request is hitting the server?

Comment: @limelights i included the full text - thanks

Comment: You're not including the call to `done()` so your tests finish and the process exits before the response arrives.

Comment: @idbehold I thought that is the problem also but checking the db shows the the record still exists, if that's the case, I would not see the response but the server would still receive the call and should delete the object